# Javascript Toggle a class on clicked class element

Tags: javascript, class, toggle

Bit of a basic one, I was unable to to find exactly what I was after on Stack/Google..

Using vanilla javascript, I'm looking to simply toggle a class on the below ***.barBtn*** elements, specifically the one I click.

Sample JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t376kL4q/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="btnBar">
        <div class="barBtn">Wishlist</div>
        <div class="barBtn">Collection</div>
        <div class="barBtn">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="btnBar">
        <div class="barBtn">Wishlist</div>
        <div class="barBtn">Collection</div>
        <div class="barBtn">Info</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I have tried adapting others' code found on Stack/Google, e.g. this one which I've JSFiddle'd: https://jsfiddle.net/5rmqucj3/

Where I changed

```
document.getElementById("mytarget").
```

to

```
document.GetElementsByClassName("mytrigger").
```

*(or even '**querySelector**')*... but I'm not sure how to correctly target the specific class element I click.

---

Whether or not the above *(2nd link)* is the best way to go about the JS of this I'm not sure, but generally just after a clean/simple way of achieving this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```js
var navclick = document.getElementsByClassName("mytrigger");
for (var i = 0; i < navclick.length; i++) {
  navclick[i].onclick = function(e) {
    this.classList.toggle('myactive');
  }
}
```

```css
.myactive {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="mytrigger">Button
    </button>

<div id="mytarget">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>

<button class="mytrigger">Button
    </button>
```

Comment: Hey K K :) Thanks for that.

If possible, is it possible for you to apply it to my first fiddle at the top? Your solution doesn't work when I use it for that - which I assume is due to them being div elements rather than button elements - though ideally I'm looking to work with divs.

No worries if not, appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @SteveyG https://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/jhed30fk/